Error in UI with status CORS error "disallowedbyPreflight Response header" in UI application
**CORS error in SPring boot 3.x mvc Apigateway and Augular 16 UI
UI calls Api gateway and both are different domains. Preflight Request is successful  with status 200. However subsequent request I am getting status CORS error " CORS error  header disallowedbyPreflightResponse"  My api gateway is build in spring boot 3.3**
Preflight Request header in browser

authority =  exchange-api-gateway.com
:method =  OPTIONS
:path  =  /v1/alerts/count
:scheme:   https
Accept : /
Accept-Encoding = gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, Channel-Type, content-type
Accept-Control-Request-Method:  GET
Origin:  https://example.com
Priority:  u=1,I
Referer: https://example.com
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fech-Mode: cors

Preflight Response header in browser

Access-Control-Allow-Credential: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers = *
Access-Control-Allow-methods = *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin= "https://example.com"
Access-Control-Expose-Headers : *
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0,private
Content-Length = 0
Date :
Expires = 0
Vary: Origin
Vary = Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary= Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options = nosniff
X-Frame-Options = Deny
X-xss-Protection = 1;mode=block

@Order(1)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

     @Override
     public void doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse,filterChain)
     {
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
       HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","https://example.com");
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
       response.addHeader("Refer-Policy","strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
       response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","X-maintainance");// tried with "*" 
       filterChain.doChain(request,response)
     }

}

I tried to use below code too
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("https://example.com")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedHeaders("authorization", "content-type", "x-custom-header") // tried with *
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .exposedHeaders("x-custom-header")// tried with * 
    

        .maxAge(3600); // 1 hour
}

